# Local php site does not run on XAMPP. Possible modrewrite issue?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am using Win 7. I downloaded XAMPP 1.7.1. I had to change the http:// localhost/ to http://localhost:8080/ as port 80 was already busy. In httpd.conf I changed AllowOverride to All.

I run a local website (php 4.2 and MySQL). The root directory of the website (located in E:\xampp\htdocs\test) contains an htaccess file.

I checked the php info to see that mod_rewrite is loaded. The htaccess file is also working correctly and is being picked up (I tried to enter nonsense text in the htaccess file and got a server error after that which confirms the htaccess is fine).

The website's home page loads fine, but it does not seem to pick up css or javascript files. The home page text and images having a direct url are shown, but any css styling isn't applied. In addition, any links to other pages just take me to http:// localhost/xampp/.

I checked the error logs and they show this error (there are a lot of lines like this):

```
[Sun May 01 22:26:57 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/xampp/htdocs/scripts, referer: http://localhost:8080/test/.
```

The htaccess file is as follows (this file works great on the remove server):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

Header unset ETag
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|pdf)$">
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [QSA,L]

#RewriteRule favicon.ico images/favicon.ico [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Thanks
Vasiliy

Update:
I played with xampp a little more and finally decided to remove the software which blocked port 80 (sql reporting services). I then changed the reference from localhost:8080 to localhost:80 in the apache config file.

Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue.

For example, the generated home page would show the following in the header:

```
<link href="http://localhost/test/styles/style.css" rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/test/scripts/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
```

The links point exactly to the location on my hard-drive where the styles.css and jquery.js are located.

At the same time a link to an image works because the image shows up:

```
<div class="logo"><img src="http://localhost/test/images/logo.png" width="356" height="77" /></div>
```

The config file for the website lists the following values which are applicable to this issue:

```
<siteHost>http://localhost/test/</siteHost>
<database>mysql://root:@localhost/prod</database>
```

Not sure what to try next. Any ideas?

Thanks
Vaciliy

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a base URL to the header of each page:

```
<head>
<base href="http://localhost:8080/" />
</head>
```

I would personally use full paths rather than relative ones when using mod_rewrite, then you wont need the above solution.

Comment: Thanks. I changed back to localhost:80, but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your paths include a leading slash.

`<link href="css/style.css" />`

is not equivalent to

`<link href="/css/style.css" />`

or

`<link href="./css/style.css" />`

Check whether this helps.

Comment: I updated my question above after I changed back to localhost:80. The link to the css file appears to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this here in order to contribute or help the OP since i can't add comments yet.

Vasiliy check if you have any htaccess file in the directory of your site, i had the same issue a while ago with images and css files and it was a mod rewrite on an htaccess file.